# Get name of running process in php

Tags: php

I've been searching and can't find something clear, at least for me

I've made a newsletter and sent it with a mail script

Since it had a lot of emails, I said ignore_user-abort and let it work sending emails even if I closed the browser

Now I'd like to check the progress, I mean, if it has finished all the emails

I understand that there are functions like posix_kill and getpid but I don't know if they are the right ones to use
getpid gives me the id but how can I know the name of the script running? Maybe another script is running that I don't know

thanks a lot

Comment: This depends on your server configuration; are you running Apache with mod_php in worker mode, preforked, or maybe using FastCGI and FPM?

Comment: make it always send an email to you after the main send is complete.  when you receive your email you know its finished.

Comment: Consider using a JobQueue, like Gearman.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Before the script start to send emails create a file by example emails.log
And when the script is done, remove it, 
When the script starts again ask if exists, and if exists kill the script, 
The only issue i see can happen is if the script dies unexpected or the page give a timeout the file will be not removed
For avoid this you can create a cronjob in your server and configure for run it daily, weekly or whatever you want, the shell script will look something like:

newsletter.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /tmp/newsletter.log ]
then
    touch /tmp/newsletter.log
    php /var/www/newsletter.php >> /dev/null
    rm /tmp/newsletter.log
fi
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm just using plain ol php cause I don't have access to the Apache server and I wouldn't know how to do it anyway (maybe through exec or system function I can try)

Comment: maybe the newxt time I will try that with the file log or even write in the database the progress

Comment: Thanks for the script, ggonzalez, is that a bash file? it should be in the root? I studied the linux commands a little but I wouldn't know where to start